# Почему не устанавливаеться muls-gcc

Tags: linux, debian, установка

Пытаюсь установить [musl-gcc](https://www.musl-libc.org/how.html) в дебиан 9

по началу пытался установить так :

```
sudo apt-get install musl-dev
```

но комп говорил что заполнен диск.

Удалил все свои файлы, а также использовал :

```
 sudo apt-get clean
 sudo apt-get avtoclean
```

В общем всё без толку  :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему то "держит" память и со мной не делиться.

Решил по другому с "пойти", установить с флешки.

```
gunzip musl-1.1.23.tar.gz
tar xvf musl-1.1.23.tar
cd musl-1.1.23
./configure
make
make install
```

ошибок не было. Все ок.

НО результат печален :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему не ставиться [musl-gcc](https://www.musl-libc.org/how.html) ???

---

Удалил все файлы и директорий `/var/log` и `/var/backups/`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но увы мне кажется что-то "держит" и не выделяет память. И я совершенно не зна что делать и куда "копать".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

да, я также разделяю мнение по поводу сбесившийся  программы забивающей всё пространство

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Аппарат специфический с КАН (сетью) и RS485.

Монитора не имеет, я  с ним по СОМ порту "общаюсь"  `sudo putty /dev/ttyUSB0 -serial -sercfg 9600,8,n,1,N`

По этому скопировать и вывести в виде текста у меня не выходит , текст не копируется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97145/discussion-on-question-by-timob256----muls-gcc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очищаем удаленные файлы, открытые работающими процессами, либо перезагрузкой, либо перезапуском соответствующих программ. Найти их можно с помощью:

```
find /proc/*/fd -ls | grep '(deleted)'
```

Для установки `musl-dev` выполняем команду:

```
sudo apt-get install musl
```

P.S. Админам на заметку: если место кончилось на неведомой железке, даже если там 3Гига, даже при явных попытках засунуть в нее "странное", со стороны коллеги, не стоит сбрасывать со счетов: `lsof (deleted)`.

Comment: Всё таки  `sudo apt-get install musl` увы оказалось маловато :3 установил ещё`sudo apt-get install musl-dev` и `sudo apt-get install musl-tools`