# Что надо сделать чтоб мертвый процесс "отпустил" диск?

Tags: linux, debian, диск

У меня проблема, какой-то PID процесс "держит" память.

Узнал я это так, поторопился вынул флешку без размонтирования. При этом сам я находился в директории на флешке (он конечно ругнулся).

После чего вставил снова флешку и решил собрать код :

```
root@R2CPU:/mnt/usb# gcc main.c -o trem_main
main.c:14:1: fatal error: error closing /tmp/cciKzlWx.s: No space left on device
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
```

[Такая ошибка у меня уже встречалась](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010785/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-muls-gcc) и я как понял она про то, что память "держит" процесс зомби , который 'блокирует' диск , после чего на любые попытки сборки выводит ошибку : не хватает памяти.

При вызове команды df выводит:

```
root@R2CPU:/# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs           87000        0     87000   0% /dev
/dev/mmcblk1p2   3096336  3096336         0 100% /
tmpfs             254532        0    254532   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             254532     3780    250752   2% /run
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             254532        0    254532   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              50904        0     50904   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  30356976 10075936  20281040  34% /mnt/usb
```

воспользовался командой :

```
find /proc/*/fd -ls | grep '(deleted)'
```

увы не сработало :

```
root@R2CPU:/# find /proc/*/fd -ls | grep '(deleted)'
root@R2CPU:/# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs           87000        0     87000   0% /dev
/dev/mmcblk1p2   3096336  3096336         0 100% /
tmpfs             254532        0    254532   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             254532     3776    250756   2% /run
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             254532        0    254532   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              50904        0     50904   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  30356976 10075936  20281040  34% /mnt/usb
root@R2CPU:/#
```

Попробовал поубивать процессы:

```
kill 584
...
kill 2
```

вызвать команду  `find /proc/*/fd -ls | grep '(deleted)'` увы снова не сработало :(

***Что надо сделать чтоб мертвый процесс "отпустил" диск ?***

---

Вот ещё попробовал :

```
root@R2CPU:/mnt/usb# TMPDIR=./tmp gcc main.c -o trem_testing
main.c:14:1: fatal error: error closing /tmp/ccdNFcF5.s: No space left on device
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Так же зашёл в директорию `tmp`

[image]

увы там ничего не лежит

---

```
root@R2CPU:/# du -h --max-depth=1
525M    ./usr
3.7M    ./run
4.0K    ./srv
du: cannot read directory './proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc': No such device
du: cannot access './proc/473/task/473/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/473/task/473/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/473/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/473/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       ./proc
8.0K    ./mnt
24K     ./tmp
4.0K    ./home
2.4G    ./var
492K    ./kononov
4.0K    ./lost+found
31M     ./lib
0       ./sys
5.2M    ./bin
136K    ./root
3.3M    ./etc
0       ./dev
4.0K    ./boot
5.4M    ./sbin
3.0G    .
root@R2CPU:/# du -shc | sort -h
du: cannot read directory './proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc': No such device
du: cannot access './proc/489/task/489/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/489/task/489/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/489/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/489/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
3.0G    .
3.0G    total
root@R2CPU:/#
```

хотелось бы удалить эти мертвые "решения" диска :

```
du: cannot read directory './proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc': No such device
    du: cannot access './proc/473/task/473/fd/4': No such file or directory
    du: cannot access './proc/473/task/473/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
    du: cannot access './proc/473/fd/3': No such file or directory
    du: cannot access './proc/473/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
```

решил " убрать" их :

```
root@R2CPU:/# du -sh 2>/dev/null
3.0G
```

.
увидя что результата нету :(

решил скачать `lsof` , думал через него решить, но увы память зомби держить сильно.

```
root@R2CPU:/# apt-get install lsof
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lsof
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 311 kB of archives.
After this operation, 421 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

---

спасибо  @andreymal , лог сбесился:

```
root@R2CPU:/var# du -h --max-depth=1
20K     ./backups
2.3G    ./log
1.9M    ./tmp
4.0K    ./mail
4.0K    ./local
52M     ./cache
76M     ./lib
4.0K    ./opt
16K     ./spool
2.4G    .
root@R2CPU:/var#
```

***Увы не знаю как правильно там всё удалить .***

Comment: `TMPDIR=./tmp gcc ...`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  попробовал, увы не взошло :(

Comment: ну, посмотрите, кто создаёт этот временный файл, и скажите ему создавать временные файлы в указанном каталоге. ну или сделайте /tmp симлинком на каталог в фс, в которой у вас есть место. // это, конечно, если вы совсем-совсем не хотите навести порядок в фс, примонтированной в корень. кстати, совершенно непонятно, почему бы вам его и не навести. ну, чтоб фс не была забита на 100%, как сейчас.

Comment: Попробуйте fuser. https://www.8host.com/blog/ispolzovanie-komandy-fuser/

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin увы в директории `tmp` я файлов не нашёл . Я даже не понимаю, что мне сделать.  И понять почему такая хрень существует.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4874762/4827341

Comment: а откуда инфа, что существует какой-то процесс который "держит" диск? Я вижу из того, что Вы предоставили, что тут просто корень переполнен и нужно поискать и возможно удалить то, что его переполнило

Comment: @nobody я уже с таким сталкивался там 2.3 гига занято  примерно 600 мигов свободно , что то похожее у меня было и там также процесс взял и схватил 600 мегабайт.

Comment: @nobody, на (некоторых) ФС есть возможность *зарезирвировать* место.

Comment: Во флешке свой микропроцессор с прошивкой. Когда вытащили флешку, могло что-то и в программе внутри флешки сбойнуть. Пока вижу первое действие — загрузка с Live образа и попытки потестировать ФС (`fsck`).

Comment: @0andriy с живого образа уже пытался запустить , у вы так и не вышло :( да и не понимаю что с fsck делать

Comment: вывод `df` соответствует выводу `du`. То есть место _не_ занимается удалёнными и не закрытыми файлами. Вы ищете не то и не там.

Comment: @nobody и как это найти ???

Comment: Вывод команды du у вас уже есть, вот по нему и смотрите, где какие файлы заняли место. Подсказка: что-то в /var и в /usr.

Comment: @andreymal  спасибо, нашёл :3 , но вот не знаю как правильно почистить лог .

Comment: 2.3G в логах! Чистить надо.

Comment: Как вариант проверить `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop/` и проверить `/var/log/`

Comment: @0andriy просто удалять `rm ` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем в директории `/var/log` было два файла с весом в 1.2 Гига каждый !

это были файлы `daemon.log` и `syslog`

В общем удалил их `rm daemon.log` и `rm syslog`, после создал командой `nano daemon.log` и  `rm syslog`.

И "перегрузил" машинку.

```
root@R2CPU:/# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs           87000      0     87000   0% /dev
/dev/mmcblk1p2   3096336 720816   2218236  25% /
tmpfs             254532      0    254532   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             254532   3784    250748   2% /run
tmpfs               5120      0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             254532      0    254532   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              50904      0     50904   0% /run/user/0
root@R2CPU:/#
root@R2CPU:/# cd var
root@R2CPU:/var# cd log
root@R2CPU:/var/log# ls
alternatives.log  btmp        dpkg.log  kern.log  syslog
apt               daemon.log  fail.log  lastlog   user.log
auth.log          debug       faillog   messages  wtmp
root@R2CPU:/var/log# du -sh ./*
0       ./alternatives.log
28K     ./apt
36K     ./auth.log
8.0K    ./btmp
8.0K    ./daemon.log
8.0K    ./debug
4.0K    ./dpkg.log
0       ./fail.log
4.0K    ./faillog
256K    ./kern.log
4.0K    ./lastlog
308K    ./messages
40K     ./syslog
76K     ./user.log
32K     ./wtmp
root@R2CPU:/var/log#
```

---

теперь все собирается :3

```
root@R2CPU:/kononov/initialization_of_deb9_n_v# gcc main.c -o trem
root@R2CPU:/kononov/initialization_of_deb9_n_v# ls
main.c  main.h  trem
```

Comment: Вам по-моему, или не Вам, боюсь ошибиться, @aleksandrbarakin говорил погуглировать в сторону `logrotate`, чтоб избежать подобного в будущем.

Comment: "удалил... создал...". Можно немного проще. `echo > daemon.log`,  `echo > syslog`

Comment: Или `truncate -s 0 файл` (для некоторых служб logrotate так и делает)